# CS Masters Prerequisite Courses

Tags: graduate-admissions, computer-science

Most Comp Sci MS programs in the US require certain undergrad core prerequisites in order for a non-CS major undergraduate to be considered for admission (usually 4 or 5 including data structures, discrete math, computer systems, etc).

If an applicant has all but one or two of these on their transcript when they apply to MS programs (e.g. late fall 2020), but plans to take the rest of the core in the semester following the application deadline (e.g. spring 2021), will their application still be taken seriously?

Is it worth mentioning plans to take the rest of the core in the statement of purpose?

Comment: Which country/countries are you asking about?

Comment: @Buffy The US. I will edit the original post.

Answer (score 1):

If you're paying nobody cares. Being rejected from a self funded masters program if you have demonstrated a degree of competency is pretty low.

Answer (score 1):

Generally this should not be too much of an issue.  For graduate classes once you enter the program, they only make sure that you have the prerequisites right before you take the class.  But since you are talking about admission here, you could mention your upcoming plans to take/finish pre-requisites in your statement of purpose.  Depending on how class registration coincides with the application deadlines for your programs of interest, the classes you intend to take may even appear on your undergrad transcript (as part of the Spring 2021 semester) when you apply to your graduate programs.  **Although, the only way to get a sure answer would be to check with the particular graduate programs that you plan on applying to to see if this will actually be an issue.**